# Do resolution settings have any impact or give any advantage in online FPS games?

Tags: opengl, collision-detection, graphics, resolution, online

There is this crazy theory that has always bothered me. I am not after a technically but more theoretically (although technical knowledge is required to) answer;

Two friends are playing the same video game over the internet (say ... CS:GO). The only difference is that Bob is playing on a 640x480 but Mike on 1900x1600.

Does the different resolution give any of them any advantage?

Comment: Do you mean resolution difference alone, with everything else being the same, or dependant on it? (FramesPerSecond, screen size, etc)

Comment: Well, if higher resolutions lower the FPS of a second player, I think advantage of the first player (friend) is obvious

Comment: @KromStern obviously the resolution has an impact on the FPS but I am more curious to know whether that has any impact on the game engine. Game engine has to somehow figure out where your single shot went exactly, wouldn't the scale of x/y/z coordinates be much greater on a higher resolution? Wouldn't the game engine have to do extra work to calculate the coordinates which would obviously have a minimal but still *some* impact on the speed of networking [(interpolation etc)](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: No. All of those calculations are performed in 3D space independent of the screen resolution. What can impact gameplay is a different FOV (field of view) as it allows one person to see more of the screen than the other

Comment: @Steven: Don't forget, that player input is done in resolution pixels before being transformed into 3D world of the game, so having 1920px gives a better precision than 800px.

Comment: @krom stern good point.

Comment: Assuming they are using something like SDL, it is likely evaluated by pixels as explained but I somehow doubt that makes a mention worthy difference in gameplay winnings.

Comment: It may be useful to look into [hit boxes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-a-hit-box) to understand how determining hit or miss is divorced from rendering and details of the character's model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The resolution *should not* affect computation of simulation logic such as "where your bullet hit." Any reasonable game will divorce such simulation data from the final render resolution of the screen. That means the main thing you're talking about with respect to resolution is what the player sees.

---

If *all other things are equal*, then a lower resolution *might* give a player a disadvantage.

A higher resolution render will be able to transmit more fine detail for objects further away. What may be reduced to 4x4 pixel smudge in the distance on a 640x480 display may be 9x9 pixels on a higher-resolution one, which may be enough additional information to convey a better sense of the color of the object which in turn may be enough to convey to the player whether the object is a friend, foe, or irrelevant.

Depending on the nature of the game, however, this may not matter; the loss of fidelity in distance rendering may only impact objects so far away that they are beyond a reasonable player's concern anyway (their weapons cannot reach them, and/or the object in question could close to a relevant range in a reasonable period of time, et cetera).

This advantage is not likely to introduce any sort of statistical significance in the win/loss rate of players, although the number of real-world factors that complicate actually testing this hypothesis are many, and consequential I doubt any real evidence exists.

---

In practice, lots of factors will be altered by a change in resolution (so all things are *not* equal). For example, it takes more processing power to render more pixels, and this can result in a decreased responsiveness to user input, conveying an advantage to the player with a lower resolution (and thus a higher responsiveness). The factors so impacted will vary depending on the specifics of the implementation of the game in question, and are far too broad to enumerate completely here.

Beyond anything else, though, I suspect players who opt to run at lower resolutions or with lower graphical settings to convey an advantage to themselves do it either because it does give them a clear boost to their FPS *or* because they *feel like* it does. It's important not to overlook the placebo effect, the fact that if a player *thinks* they have an advantage they may play better regardless of whether or not they *actually* have one (the opposite is also true).

Perhaps to reinforce this point, most players don't seem to really understand what "FPS" is measuring (and specifically, how it's a non-linear measurement) and will bend over backwards to push 5 FPS on to a game running at 500, not realizing how small of fraction of time that is. They nonetheless may assert that they perform much better at 505 FPS than 500, which is almost certainly attributed to the placebo effect.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the resolutions @vba4all mentioned are of different aspect ratios, which could result in different information displayed to either player, unless there were some type of letterboxing.

Comment: That's a good point, I guess I'd assume letterboxing is used for the "all things equal" case (since otherwise, as you note, you see more; this can matter more in top-down or sidescroller games than FPSs but is still worth equalizing for the same reasons)

Comment: Just to add as a note: there are some games (Quake-based games like CoD) which send a packet each frame. This means that the higher FPS you have, the more packets you're sending.

Comment: @AcidShout that's also a valid point. I think that the [interpolation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) accounts for the equality in networking. From the article it seems that graphics ( or rather the FPS rate each player gets ) does matter.

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. Also, it's important to know that some games have the so hated `antilag`. It basically takes your packet time and rolls back the server till your exact moment, executes your packet, then continues. If you manage to disable all kinds of prediction (meaning that all you see is **exact** player positions for that time), you may see bad animations, but all your hits will actually hit (supposing you're aiming at a hitbox). Prediction sometimes doesn't help as much as described. (and what I said is valid specifically for CoD MW3. I don't know if it's valid for other games.)

Answer (score 0):

**Pros**

1. Higher resolution should give the player more visual information about the game world. Everything will be clearer and more sharply defined. This should confer an advantage in overall situational awareness, which in an FPS is important.
2. There should be no effect on game state as the game engine does not compute the position of objects and actors based on screen resolution but on resolution independent internal map co-ordinates or something along those lines.

**Cons**

1. The higher the resolution, the lower the frame rate as the hardware has to do more work to render each frame and it has a finite processing capacity. Frame rates lower than around 20 frames per second are too slow for games where there is a lot of action and the camera (point of view) is changing a lot as movement of objects in the field of view will become less noticable.

This one requires a little more explanation. The human visual system is quite good at identifying and tracking moving objects (whether they be prey, predator or environmental hazard), and less good at identifying static objects (or in our case, objects whose movement is rendered with low fidelity due to reduced framerate).

In an FPS, much of the game play revolves around rapidly identifying and assessing potential targets and threats and forumlating a suitable response (i.e. "twitch" gaming). Strategies tend to be more of a secondary layer, but the twitch is more important.

For slower paces games such an RPGs a framerate a low as 15 FPS may be acceptable, but anything below 10 FPS is very noticeable and rapidly becomes a slideshow.

**TL;DR**

You must strike a balance between high detail (higher resolution) and smooth action (higher framerate).

Comment: 20 FPS is definitely unacceptable for networked games. You should add the frameTime to latency. Also, greater resolutions also mean more complex assets wich may have additional latency during streaming even with powerfull PCs. but I fear there are other settings in game that may favour a player.